# Custom generic SetFlag / UnsetFlag extension methods

Tags: c#, generics, enums

In my childish naïvety, I decided to build generic `SetFlag` and `UnsetFlag` extension methods for Enums, so no one has to read and reread and rereread the bitwise operators all over my code:

```
public static void SetFlag<T>(this T en, T flag)  where T : Enum {
    en |= flag;
}
```

and

```
public static void UnsetFlag<T>(this T en, T flag) where T : Enum
{
    en &= ~flag;
}
```

Now I get the errors that operator `|=` is not applicable to types `T` and `T` and operator `~` is not applicable to type `T`.

I think that I have to change `T` to the type "`Enum` with `HasFlags`". Is this the true root of the problem, and how would I change that?

Comment: Don't you get the error that `System.Enum` isn't allowed as type parameter constraint?

Comment: @ThomasLielacher Nope, I don't get that error.

Comment: Interesting. Which IDE are you using? I've pasted your code into a Visual Studio 2013 project and it instantly showed an error saying: "Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Enum'"

Comment: @ThomasLielacher Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4; Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.51209

Comment: I've tried around a little bit, but I have the feeling, that this isn't doable in an elegant and save way. I managed to get the methods working but it doesn't feel "right". If you know what I mean.

Comment: @ThomasLielacher I understand, nevertheless, I did _not_ get it working and I would be interested in your solution. Even if I won't put it into production code, would be nice to see how you did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my methods. As I said in the comments to the question, I strongly discourage from using this methods in production code:

```
    public static T SetFlag<T>(this T en, T flag) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        int value = en.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        int newFlag = flag.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return (T)(object)(value | newFlag);
    }

    public static T UnsetFlag<T>(this T en, T flag) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        int value = en.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        int newFlag = flag.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return (T)(object)(value & ~newFlag);
    }
```

Usage:

```
[Flags]
public enum Flags
{
    None = 0, A = 1, B = 2, C = 4
}

Flags flags = Flags.A.SetFlag(Flags.C);
flags = flags.UnsetFlag(Flags.C);
```

As you can see I made use of it, that every enum implements `IConvertible`. So I defined extension methods on this interface which also provides a handy method for converting the value of the enum to an `int`. A side effect of this is that you can use this methods for every other type which implements this interface. So you could abuse this methods for something like this:

```
int a = 0;
a = a.SetFlag(5); // a == 5
a = a.UnsetFlag(4); // a == 1
```